# Why is TokenID kept private?

Tags: erc-721

A lot of NFT protocols I've seen privitize their counters object that tracks the tokenID of new NFTs minted on the contract. My question is, why? Doesn't this just make it much harder to access the list of TokenURIs from the frontend?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it is an implementation detail. Developers are free to decide what ids they would use. For some use cases it makes sense for them to be consecutive numbers for other use cases it is better if they are completely random, and there are projects where ids are allocated in ranges.

The [EIP-721](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721) defines the optional interface `ERC721Enumerable` for browsing existing tokens. Unfortunately it is not implemented by everyone.